# Keynote: Is there a way to make a Progress bar automatically

Tags: iwork-keynote

Make all my presentations in Keynote.
At the moment I manually make a progress bar on the button of each page. It's 3px high and depending on what page we are on the width will reflect that.

For a presentation with 10 pages, the progress bar on page 1 will be 1/10. and so on.

Is there a way to automate this...? like ex. pagenumber...